# Spring BeanFactory product autowiring

Tags: java, spring

I want to have something like this:

```java
@Servise
public class BeanAFactory implements FactoryBean<BeanA>{

    @Autowired <…>;

    @Override
    public BeanA getObject() throws Exception {
        return new BeanAImpl();
    }

    @Override
    public Class<BeanA> getObjectType() {
        return BeanA.class;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isSingleton() {
        return false;
    }

    private class BeanAImpl implements BeanA {
        <…>
    }
}
```

and to have autowiring of result of `BeanAFactory.getObject()` on `BeanA`: `ctx.getBean(BeanA.class)` should return result of `BeanAFactory.getObject()`. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Declare object of `BeanA` in `BeanAFactory` class and initialize it in using default constructor so you will get that object while autowiring `BeanAFactory` class.

Comment: Could you explicate your answer, unfortunately I couldn't get what do you mean.